# May a warm reset by pulling down the reset pin of the SoC cause the file system corrupts?

Tags: filesystems, hardware, embedded-linux

In my embedded Linux system, I made a hardware switch to pull down the reset pin of the SoC(TI DM365). When the system is running, I can push the button to reboot the system. I want to know whether this behavior is safe to my file system or it will cause a corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems to be a bad idea to reset the SoC that way, the effects it may have on your filesystem depends on your filesystem setup. For instance, you can have read-only filesystems; or you can use powercut-tolerant filesystems such as UBIFS on NAND flashes.

That said, having access to the SoC reset line may be good as a last resource measure, when everything else failed, and your system is already foobared.

You can provide a graceful reboot/poweroff, by simply exposing a GPIO triggering a soft reboot/poweroff.